# Why are my cart contents not showing on Justhost Server but showing on local server?

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, shopping-cart, cart

I have a php shopping cart which uses cookies to remember the users items.

It works fine on my local wamp sever, I add or remove items and view them in my cart. However, when I upload the site to JustHost to see how it looks online, I can still add items to my cart and see the product page, but when I click on the cart to see what I have in the cart I can only see my navbar, my footer is broken too and drop-down menus in navbars don't work.

Here is the code for my cart page:

```
<?php
$page_title="Cart";
include '/includes/header.php';
include './config/config.php';

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";

if($action=='removed'){
echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> was removed from your cart!";
echo "</div>";
}

$cookie = $_COOKIE['cart_items_cookie'];
$cookie = stripslashes($cookie);
$saved_cart_items = json_decode($cookie, true);

if(count($saved_cart_items)>0){
// get the product ids
$ids = "";
foreach($saved_cart_items as $id=>$name){
    $ids = $ids . $id . ",";
}

// remove the last comma
$ids = rtrim($ids, ',');

//start table
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";

    // our table heading
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Price (USD)</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $query = "SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id IN ({$ids})     ORDER BY name";
    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_price=0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
            echo "<td>&#36;{$price}</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<a href='remove_from_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='btn btn-danger'>";
                    echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Remove from cart";
                echo "</a>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $total_price+=$price;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><b>Total</b></td>";
            echo "<td>&#36;{$total_price}</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<a href='payment-page.php' class='btn btn-success'>";
                    echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Checkout";
                echo "</a>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
}

else{
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
    echo "<strong>No products found</strong> in your cart!";
echo "</div>";
}

include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Please can someone advise if there is something I have missed out of my cart page code (or if I should be adding something to another file..) that is preventing me from seeing anything when this page is viewed

Thanks for any help

Comment: double check your includes. speaking of if you are able to - put your config above the html public root of your server so its not directly accessible. also with respect i would suggest you consider eventually using a framework. especially with e-commerce there is so much involved - a framework is a great help especially with security.

Comment: Thanks, includes seem fine, I have changed them all to this format: include 'includes/header.php';
include 'config/config.php';

Comment: which framework would you recommend? I am building the website with Bootstrap/less

Comment: did you mean take the config file out of the websites file and put it in the html public root?

Comment: One level Above the public root. especially if your config file has sensitive info - like your database user / pass - then its safer if you put it Above the public html folder.

Comment: I'm using the codeigniter framework for e-commerce and its awesome. Very easy to learn, no dependencies on 3rd party code, updated frequently, friendly community. Also the fastest performing full featured PHP framework. Easiest is to start with the tutorial http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: okay great thanks I will check it out. Can you see any problems with the above PHP cart code? My footer isn't showing so I am assuming there must be an error in the code. My footer and cart does show on local server but not on my online server..

Comment: well i said to check the includes because at the top you have include '/includes/header.php'; and at the bottom you have include 'includes/footer.php'; - uh so don't know your file structure but do you need a forward slash for the footer link?

Comment: yeah i added one, tried many variations :( must be php error, rest of cart functions work

Comment: fixed! copy and pasted code from wamp and it worked!! thanks